# Singular Model,Controller, Form_for reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a singular model, controller, view named "product".  In my routes, I used activemodel so there is no pluralization.

## Routes:

```
resource :product, :controller => 'product'
```

When I use form_for:

```
<%= form_for( @product) do |f| %>
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined method `products_path'
```

How do I fix this?  It should be product_path.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution.  There are two methods to do this.

1) Add this to the Model file. `model_name.instance_variable_set(:@route_key, 'product')`

OR

2) `= form_for @product, :url => product_path do |f|`

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use the plural for your *controller name* (as per convention), and singular for the *route*:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :products, controller: "product", path: "product" #-> url.com/product/:id
```

Comment: You should use `resources`. Using resource on his singular form will produce routes as we'll never get more than one product. So without parametric routes

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
#config/routes.rb    
resources :product, :controller => 'product'
```

For `create` action it generates alias `product_index` for "/product" path

But `form_for` don't know that and, by convention, will look for `products_path`, producing your error.

I think it's best to adapt routes to keep `form_for` to be abble to work on his own (for new/create and edit/update)

We assume that you have your singular controller, it could be to much pain to change that in your app, so we stay with it.

What you can do in your routes

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :product, only: [:index, :create], as: :products
resources :product, except: [:index, :create]
```

For create action, that will produce:

```
POST "/product" => "product#create", as: "products"
```

And `form_for` will be happy